# How to open a random video from a playlist in py 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently switched from Chrome to Firefox and one of my programs that I use to generate a random song from a playlist has stopped working. This was the code that I used when I used Chrome (instead of firefox_path it said chrome_path). Is there something about Firefox that makes this not work or have I made a mistake in my code that I can't see?

```
import webbrowser as web
import secrets
firefox_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe %s'
ytplaylist = [elem1, elem2, elem3]
B64Code = secrets.choice(ytplaylist)
vid = 'youtube.com/watch?v=' + B64Code
web.get(firefox_path).open(vid)
```

Comment: You could try it from the command line first. From the top of my head: I would check what happens if you add `http://` or `https://` in front of the URL.

Comment: Adding https:// or http:// didn't change anything. how would I go about doing this from the command line? I need the %s or it says: raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

Comment: As the documentation says, *When the value of a list part contains the string %s, then it is interpreted as a literal browser command line to be used with the argument URL substituted for `%s`*. So it is going to be end up as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe youtube.com/watch?v=something`. You can try if FF would launch the video correctly when issuing this command from a `cmd` window.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, escape (the backslashes) and quote (the command with spaces inside), then it works:

```
firefox_path = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" %s'
```

My complete test looks like this:

```
import webbrowser as web
firefox_path = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" %s'
vid = 'youtube.com/watch?v=f4f1TT3B--Y'
web.get(firefox_path).open(vid)
```